# Check if Text Message contains a Word and if yes send a CustomText

Tags: python

I use a working python script to Check Crypto Coin Price drops, If a Coin drops -3% or more I get a message in Telegram and the same Message is sent to my Email.

Now I want to send a Custom Text for every Market like BTC/ETH/USDT and so on...

I want with python to Check the message and If Message Contains a price drop from BTC Market send text1
ETH Market send text2
USDT Market send text3

The Bot gets the CoinName like this Example: IOTA/BTC < In this case I need the bot to see the word BTC and Send text1. I tryed some things but can't figure it out.

Here the section where the text for the Message is,

```
`bot.send_message(parse_mode='HTML', chat_id=BINANCE_ID,
 text = "<a href = 'https://www.binance.com/tradeDetail.html?symbol {C}_{M}'> {Coin} </a> ".format(C = CoinItself,
                                                                                                                                     M = Market,
                                                                                                                                     Coin = Coin)
                   + "▼" + str(RoundPercent) + "%  "
                   + str(floatDictPrice) + " -> "
                   + str(floatDataPrice) + "  [Binance]")
 binance_prices.update( { CurrentCoin: dataPrice })
 send_message("<a href = 'https://www.binance.com/tradeDetail.html?symbol={C}_{M}'> {Coin} </a> ".format(C = CoinItself,
                                                                                                                                     M = Market,
                                                                                                                                     Coin = Coin)
                    + "▼" + str(RoundPercent) + "%  "
                    + str(floatDictPrice) + " -> "
                    + str(floatDataPrice) + "  [Binance]")`
```

The `bot.send_message` section sends the message to telegram & the `send_message` section sends the same Message text to my Email.

```
`search_word = input("BTC")
if(search_word == send_message):
    print("text1")
else:
    print("word not found")`
```

I tried this one. Any Ideas how to get this working?

Comment: The operator you are looking for is `in` - `if search_word in send_message:`

Comment: So you mean instead of `==` i need to put here `in` ?

Answer (score 0):

What [AChampion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52084973/check-if-text-message-contains-a-word-and-if-yes-send-a-customtext#comment91120175_52084973) means is the following:

```
if search_word in send_message:
    print("text1")
else: 
    print("word not found")
```

Comment: Everytime I try to add this code Above the other texts or below or inside, the script don't starts anymore, Can it be that with with Command only Files are Searchable not the text the Bot gets from the API? Or something in the first line `search_word = input("BTC")` ?